# iOS MPMoviePlayer issue on iPod touch 2G

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, mpmovieplayer

I have an universal application which plays several imbedded movies. All works fine on my iPad with iOS 4.2 and on my iPhone 4 with iOS 4.2.1. However on my iPod touch 2G with iOS 4.2.1, the movies don't play. There is no crash or other interruption of the app, the movies just don't play. While in debug mode I got the following error message from the console:

```
H264Decoder ERROR:  This level: 31, is not supported.
```

I'm confused, why the movies play on one device but don't play on another with the same iOS version. The movies are mp4 movies with the H.264 codec.

Comment: I'm also seeing this problem with my iPod with iOS 4.1 and my client is reporting a similar issue with their iPods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that your video is H.264's Main Profile. This is supported by the iPod Touch 4th gen, but not the iPod touch gen 2 and gen 3 - these support only Low Complexity Baseline and Baseline profiles.